# Организация параллельного процесса в приложении на Swift

Tags: ios, многопоточность, swift, swift4

С вопросом к знатокам обращается начинающий **iOS**-разработчик (**Swift**).

На досуге решил написать для себя и друзей простую (логическую, не анимированную) игру с обыкновенными лейблами, списками, инпутами и прочей дефолтной дребеденью.

Однако встрял на самом главном и самом сложном, для меня, моменте.

В игре есть два объекта - **Герой** и **Монстр**.
Основной процесс игры это битва этих двух объектов.

У каждого из них есть параметры: **Attack** (*Int*), **HP** (*Int*) и **AttackDelay** (*Float*).

Суть вопроса заключается в следующем:

Каким образом организовать процесс их одновременной битвы, чтобы она заканчивалась в случае, если параметр **HP** одного из них станет равен нолю?

Как я понимаю - без всевозможных **Threads/GCD/NSOperations** здесь не обойтись? Но даже если так, то... как? =)

Заранее благодарю за возможные ответы.

Comment: Т.к написали, что не анимирована, какая идея будет? Нажали на кнопочку - нужен результат, т.е. кто победил? Или же Вы будете по времени все показывать: монстр нанес столько-то повреждений, герой столько-то, осталось столько и так до конца?

Comment: @VAndrJ, в дальнейшем хотелось бы видеть хотя бы базовый **ProgressBar** и возможность влиять на ход битвы путём использования зелий (к примеру - лечащих).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать `DispatchSourceTimer` Асинхронный таймер.

Пример решение

Создаем таймеры для каждого персонажа.

```
var timerHero: DispatchSourceTimer?
var timerMoster: DispatchSourceTimer?
```

А также характеристики персонажей

```
var hero = 25
var monster = 30

let speedMonster = 1.5
let speedHero = 0.8

let attackHero = 5
let attackMonster = 3
```

Для каждого таймера можно создать отдельный метод.

В каждом методе необходимо реализовать:

1. Инициализация асихронной очереди.
2. Переход таймера в `nill` (на случай если не затерся)
3. Инициализация таймера с очередью созданной выше.
4. Запуск `schedule` с определенным интервалом повторения.
5. Запуск замыкания (реализация кода таймера будет происходить здесь)
6. Если в замыкании требуется обновлять пользовательский интерфейс, то его надо обновлять в основной очереди. `DispatchQueue.main.async`
7. Запуск таймера.

Пример

```
private func startMonsterTimer() {
    let monstarQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "monstarQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    timerMoster?.cancel()
    timerMoster = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: monstarQueue)
    timerMoster?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: speedMonster)
    timerMoster?.setEventHandler(handler: { [unowned self] in
      self.hero -= self.attackMonster
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Update UI

        print("hero HP \(self.hero)")

        if self.hero <= 0 {
          print("monster is Win")
          self.storTimers()
        }
      }
    })
    timerMoster?.resume()
  }

private func startHeroTimer() {
    let heroQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "heroQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    timerHero?.cancel()
    timerHero = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: heroQueue)
    timerHero?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: speedHero)
    timerHero?.setEventHandler(handler: { [unowned self] in
      self.monster -= self.attackHero
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Update UI

        print("monster HP \(self.monster)")

        if self.monster <= 0 {
          print("hero is Win")
          self.storTimers()
        }
      }
    })
    timerHero?.resume()
  }
```

Как только один из таймеров выполнил необходимую задачу, их необходимо удалить.

```
private func storTimers() {
    timerHero?.cancel()
    timerHero = nil

    timerMoster?.cancel()
    timerMoster = nil
  }
```

Вот в принципе и все.

Таймеры можно запустить в любом удобном для вас методе, например в `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startMonsterTimer()
    startHeroTimer()
  }
```

Comment: Потрясающий ответ. Огромное спасибо.


И, пользуясь случаем, хотелось бы уточнить у знающего человека следующий момент: есть ли в текущем подходе возможность вмешательства в процесс извне? Допустим - выпить лечащее зелье или нанести монстру дополнительный урон путём клика (тапа) по экрану?

Ещё раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: Конечно да, это можно делать за пределами таймера.